# Does Sublimerl work well in windows?

Tags: erlang, sublimetext2

I tried [Sublimerl](https://github.com/ostinelli/SublimErl) in Sublime Text 2 under Windows 7. The auto-completion did not work well. All the function names, whether they belong to the module or not, appeared in the popup box, like this: [image]

I also checked the key-bindings under the [bindings folder](https://github.com/ostinelli/SublimErl/tree/master/bindings), but only Linux and OSX in this folder. Does it mean Sublimerl does not support Windows well?

Answer (score 1):

The lack of any mention of windows in the documentation of [Sublimerl](http://github.com/ostinelli/SublimErl) and the ticket ["May I ask when will sublimerl support on windows?"](http://github.com/ostinelli/SublimErl/issues/67) seems to indicate that there is no real support for windows.

Answer (score 1):

SublimerErl author here.

As @jan said, no support for windows yet. Feel free to contribute.

r.